# Can a clicktag-enabled Flash ad be presented without an ad server?

Tags: flash, wordpress, ads, clicktag

I am new to the world of online advertising and know almost nothing about developing Flash.

I run a WordPress website for a local magazine, and they recently acquired an advertiser who wants to advertise with Flash on our website. (All ads up until now have been images, animated or otherwise, which I surrounded with a hyperlink.) I assumed that presenting the Flash ad was as simple as embedding the `<object>` HTML that referenced the .swf file, but although the ad would load, clicking on it produced no result. I contacted the advertiser to tell them their link wasn't working, but they asked what our 'clicktag' requirements were. Confused, I did some Googling, and learned what a clicktag is.

After an hour or so of researching on Google, Wikipedia, and StackOverflow, I'm a little confused about what I need to set up to present this ad. Assuming the advertiser built their SWF properly (which, now that I've made them check it, I assume they did), is it simply a matter of presenting the ad through an ad server that supports clicktag? Or is there a way of presenting it without an ad server?

We do not have an an ad server, and the second question is: if we need one, which ad network would be a good fit for us? (Our website is relatively small — only about 200 visits a day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you embed your swf, passing a URL to it is simple:

```
<param name="movie" value="MYSWF.swf?clickTAG=MYURL" />
```

You see? Just append `?clickTAG=` and your URL and you should be good to go.

If you need more detailed information please post your full embed code.

Comment: So the clicktag is something set in the HTML embed code and not in the SWF file itself? Will that provide the same analytics hooks to the advertiser?

Comment: The clicktag is a mechanism that allows you to dynamically send a URL to a banner. This can be via javascript or a param (like in my example). If your advertiser wants analytics you either have to send it through an adserver or they have to look into their log files to see how many visitors you referred to them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clicktag
Basically your advertiser is asking what parameter you're sending that contains the URL.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense now. I didn't understand what they were asking for, or that the clicktag was an external parameter. (I had misunderstood it as a part of the SWF that served as a trackable alternative to a hyperlink button.)